# Is it possible to convert this powershell script to batch?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

This is the script:

```
$devid = "*HID\VID_0EEF&PID_A001&REV_1213&Col01"
$status = devcon status $devid | Select-String "running"
if($status -eq $null) {
write-host "Enabling touch"
devcon enable $devid
} else {
write-host "Disabling touch"
devcon disable $devid
devcon restart $devid
}
```

And this is what I have:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET devid="HID\VID_0EEF&PID_A001&REV_1213&Col01"
set status=
for /f "tokens=10" %%i in ('devcon status %devid%') do @set status=%%i
IF %status%==running (
devcon enable %devid%
) ELSE (
devcon disable %devid%
devcon restart %devid%
)
```

But this does not work and I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you left out the * wildcard from %devid%?

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
set "devid=HID\VID_0EEF&PID_A001&REV_1213&Col01"
devcon status "%devid%" | find "running" > nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    devcon enable "%devid%"
) else (
    devcon disable "%devid%"
    devcon restart "%devid%"
)
```

Search (`find`) for string. Check if found (`not errorlevel 1`) or not found

Comment: Sorry, I had not devcon to test and written without tests. Glad you got it to work. Updated answer. Thank you

Comment: It works if this way:

`@echo off
set "devid=HID\VID_0EEF&PID_A001&REV_1213&Col01"
devcon status "%devid%" | find "running" > nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    devcon enable "%devid%"
) else (
    devcon disable "%devid%"
    devcon restart "%devid%"
)`

Thanks!